# Multi language support is not working

Tags: 6, i18n-l10n

I want to the content of a content type to be available in two languages. One is English(default) and other is Chinese(simplified).

So I add language Chinese(simplified) from "admin/settings/language/add" and then download the .po files for the language and import the files for the Chinese(simplified) language.

Then I enable my content type's Multi language support with "Enabled, content translation".

Then I create the a content of that content type and select the Chinese(simplified) language from the language drop down.

But the content of that node is displaying in English language and I have selected the chinese language while creating the content. So its content is not displaying in the Chinese language?

Any Idea or help will be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: .po files will not work that away I beleive, its just like a properties files in J2EE apps. its a list of `key = value` where key is in Eng and value in other language(chinese) so if it matches a key it will replace. And I dont think whole paragraph translation will work.

Comment: so what should I do then?

Comment: The .po files do translate the core and module texts. There's nothing wrong with that. However it's not related to the translation of the data saved in your content type.

Comment: hmmm, @BetaRide then what should I use for the translation of the data saved in my content type?

Comment: Either you put in Translated Data in nodes or put english and chinese data in po files.